# Combining TypeScript Methods for Processing Data into Charts

Tags: typescript

I have two TypeScript methods in my project that are similar in their functionality. Both methods process input data and generate output data that I can then feed into different chart components. One method (processCategoryData) processes category data, and the other (processDateData) processes date data. The main difference between them is the shape of the output data: ChartDataCategory[] for category data and ChartDataDate[] for date data.

`ChartDataCategory` looks this this `{ value: string, count: number }`

And `ChartDataDate` like this `{ date: number, value: number }`.

Here are the two methods:

```js
  private processCategoryData(
    data: Customer[],
    keySelector: (item: Customer) => string
  ): ChartDataCategory[] {
    const result: ChartDataCategory[] = [];

    data.forEach((item) => {
      const keyValue = keySelector(item);

      const existingItem = result.find((obj) => obj.value === keyValue);

      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.count += 1;
      } else {
        result.push({ value: keyValue, count: 1 });
      }
    });

    return result;
  }

  private processDateData(
    data: Customer[],
    keySelector: (item: Customer) => number
  ): ChartDataDate[] {
    const result: ChartDataDate[] = [];

    data.forEach((item) => {
      const keyValue = keySelector(item);

      const existingItem = result.find((obj) => obj.date === keyValue);

      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.value += 1;
      } else {
        result.push({ date: keyValue, value: 1 });
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
```

I've been trying to find a way to combine these two methods into one to avoid code repetition, but I'm facing some challenges with TypeScript's type system. I'm relatively new to TypeScript and struggling with type gymnastics. I understand the basic use of generics but apparently not enough to do something like this.

Can anyone help me with a solution or provide guidance on how to effectively combine these methods?

Thanks!

Edit: specified data types contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, but I am not sure it is more legible.

further, my attempts to do type gymnastics to avoid 'any' meant that
a) I had to write more code than the original
b) code readability was further decreased

```
 private processCategoryData(
    data: Customer[],
    keySelector: (item: Customer) => string
  ): ChartDataCategory[] {
    return this.processData<ChartDataCategory>(data, keySelector, 'value', 'count');
  }

  private processDateData(
    data: Customer[],
    keySelector: (item: Customer) => number
  ): ChartDataDate[] {
    return this.processData<ChartDataDate>(data, keySelector, 'date', 'value');
  }

  private processData<T>(data: Customer[],
    keySelector: (item: Customer) => string | number,
    countKey: string,
    valueKey: string): T[] {
    let result: T[] = [];
    data.forEach((item) => {
      const keyValue = keySelector(item);

      const existingItem = result.find((obj) => (obj as any)[valueKey] == keyValue);

      if (existingItem) {
        (existingItem as any)[valueKey] += 1;
      } else {
        result.push({ [valueKey]: keyValue, [countKey]: 1 } as T);
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Although there's a small error. You're incrementing value instead of count `(existingItem as any)[valueKey] += 1;` should be `(existingItem as any)[countKey] += 1;`